# Including '..' Entry in Directory Listings Produced by http.server

Tags: python, python-3.x, http.server

Is there a way to instruct python3's http.server to include a '..' entry for the parent directory in the listing for a subdirectory (excluding such an entry, of course, for the root directory itself)?

If the answer is 'no' and one has to instead develop a custom handler, is there an implementation of such a handler provided in the python3 distribution?